# filter_input() c массивом

Tags: php

Есть входные данные вида

```
array(2) 
 {
   [0]=> array(2) 
   {
     ["t"] => string(1) "1"
     ["a"] => string(2) "a1"
   }
   [1]=> array(2) 
   {
     ["t"] => string(1) "2"
     ["a"] => string(2) "a2"
   }
}
```

Можно ли как-нибудь через `filter_input()` задать фильтр `FILTER_VALIDATE_INT` для элементов массива `test[]["t"]` ?
Если нельзя, то не подскажете в каком направлении копать, чтобы написать свою функцию фильтрацией такого массива?

З.Ы. пока это выглядит как
`filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'test', FILTER_DEFAULT, FILTER_REQUIRE_ARRAY)`

Comment: А что должно происходить, если элемент `[]['t']` не прошел фильтрацию?

Comment: Тоже самое, что и `filter_input()`. Т.е. **FALSE** или значение по умолчанию, если оно задано.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$data = [
    [
        "t" => "1",
        "a" => "a1",
        ],
    [
        "t" => "2",
        "a" => "a2",
        ],
    ];

$args = [
    't' => FILTER_VALIDATE_INT,
    'a' => FILTER_VALIDATE_INT,
    ];

$data = array_map(function ($value) use ($args) {
        return filter_var_array($value, $args);
    }, $data);


// var_dump($data);
// 
// array (size=2)
//   0 => 
//     array (size=2)
//       't' => int 1
//       'a' => boolean false
//   1 => 
//     array (size=2)
//       't' => int 2
//       'a' => boolean false
```